# May someone explain this mod_rewrite of Apache to me?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.test.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

I get the first line: `RewriteEngine On` and I get the regex of RewriteCond.

But I'm having trouble comprehending the 3rd line. How are we able to capture the next part after `.net` using '(.*)' *in line 3*? Shouldn't the `(.*)` be in the 2nd line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064636/may-someone-explain-this-mod-rewrite-of-apache-to-me):

> ```
> RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
> ```

The first argument, `(.*)` is the pattern.

> What is matched?
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against
>   the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query
>   string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be
>   matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that
>   led the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or
>   "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

Answer (score 1):

the first parameter of rewrite rule relates the the URI, `(.*)` means capture any string.

Also a not on the condition, you shouldn't have the initial `.` after www, should just be `!^www\.test\.com$`

Comment: That dot was a mistake, edited. :) Now, I know what `(.*)` means, however, like the question stated, how does `(.*)` in the 3rd line knows what's going on in the second line?

Comment: because RewriteRule obeys all prior RewriteConds, and the (.*) part has no idea whats going on in the second line, its just matching the URI.